# Fatal exception when i try to set bitmap on background of imageView

Tags: android, exception, bitmap, imageview, android-drawable

i get

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.widget.ImageView.setBackground
    at ua.khuta.mobilereception.ProfileActivity.onCreate(ProfileActivity.java:117)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

in this line

```
imageView.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),k));
```

All work fine on Android 4.4.2, but it does not work on lower versions. Part of my manifest is

```
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please try this:

```
int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if(sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
    //if you want take image from resources - getResources().getDrawable(your_id)
    imageView.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),k)));

} else {
    imageView.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),k));
}
```

Comment: what must i put instead "here_your_drawable"?

Comment: getResources().getDrawable(your_id) or you can use new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),k) as well. You just need create from your bitmap - drawable